# Enviar request.session cada vez que renderizo una pagina

Tags: nodejs, express, handlebars

En todas las vistas de mi proyecto necesito imprimir el nombre de usuario, el cual guardo en el objeto request.session de el router de express, entonces necesito alguna forma de enviar dicho parametro a las vistas cada vez que renderizo una pagina sin tener que indicarlo cada vez.

Mi codigo:

```
router.get('/horario', async(request, response)=>{
    const schedule = await alumn_obj.getSchedule(request.session.id_user)
    response.render('alumn/schedule.alumn.hbs',{
        schedule,
        name: request.session.name_user
    })
})

router.get('/calificaciones', async(request, response)=>{
    const subjects = await alumn_obj.getQualifications(request.session.id_user);
    response.render('alumn/qualifications.alumn.hbs', {
        subjects,
        name: request.session.name_user
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basta con que agregues un middleware que se encargue de llenar los datos que necesita tu plantilla.

```
router.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.locals.name = request.session.name_user
    next()
})
```

Luego tus rutas se simplifican a

```
router.get('/horario', async (request, response) => {
    const schedule = await alumn_obj.getSchedule(request.session.id_user) 
    response.render('alumn/schedule.alumn.hbs', { schedule })
})

router.get('/calificaciones', async (request, response) => {
    const subjects = await alumn_obj.getQualifications(request.session.id_user);
    response.render('alumn/qualifications.alumn.hbs', { subjects })
})
```

Puesto que `name` ya ha sido agregado al contexto de la plantilla a través de `res.locals`

> [`res.locals`](https://expressjs.com/es/api.html#res.locals) An object that contains response local variables scoped to the request, and therefore available only to the view(s) rendered during that request / response cycle (if any).